# python: alter setup.py to search local file system directory for required dependencies

Tags: python, installation, setup.py, build-dependencies

My project depends on lots of packages.  Some are listed on pypi, some are not.

I now have a folder named "external-packages" where I keep .tar.gz files of the packages that I need that are not on pypi.

I want to alter setup.py so that when it reads the install_requires section and finds a package that is not yet installed, first, it should look in the "external-packages" folder, and then if that fails, then it should go search on pypi.

Is this possible?  How to do this?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Have you tried adding `external-packages` to your PYTHONPATH?

Comment: I have not tried that.  The files in external-packages are .tar.gz files of source code.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you use setuptools/distribute (indicated by `install_requires` option). You could use `dependency_links` setting in `setup.py` but it limits your options to distribute your package. For example, you might use one set of dependencies for development, several sets for testing, yet another set for a debian package, etc.

Both [`easy_install`](http://packages.python.org/distribute/easy_install.html#installing-on-un-networked-machines), [`pip install`](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/usage.html#install-packages) provide `--find-links`, `--index` options that you could specify at the command-line, in config files. It allows to use the right set of requirements for each specific case without editing `setup.py`.

You could also use [requirements files](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/requirements.html#requirements-files) to specify what versions should be installed and where to get them.

Comment: So, if I write a requirements.txt file, I should probably remove the install_requires section from setup.py, right?

Comment: @W.MatthewWilson: no/yes. It depends on your use case e.g., if your users should be able `pip install your_package` then [non-vendorized dependencies](http://bitprophet.org/blog/2012/06/07/on-vendorizing/) that are available on pypi could be specified in `install_requires`. To install development environment you could: `pip install -r requirements/dev.txt; pip install --no-deps -e .`. Your CI server could: `pip install -r requirements/test-py2.4.txt`. A rpm-package might use `python setup.py build` without installed `setuptools` and ignore both `install_requires` and `requirements` files.